# CSS rounded corners in iframe in Safari

Tags: css, safari, rounded-corners

I'm trying include iframe with rounded edges - my solution works fine in IE9, FF, Chrome, but not in Safari. Is any way (JS, CSS, etc) to have iframe with rounded edges?
Currently I have following code:

```
.somediv iframe{
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you're better off giving `.somediv` if its the immediate parent the rounded corners. Rounded corners definitely work on `div`'s in safari.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `border-radius` on a wrapper div *and* set `overflow:hidden` on it as well. Haven’t tried it, but it could work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the problem still exist in Safari (in FF and Chrome is fine).

Answer (score 1):

Rounded corners definitely work on div in Safari... but not if you add an iframe.
Please check out the code, which is below - it doesn't work in any browser...
but if you change:

```
<div class="somediv" >
    <iframe class="" ...>
```

to

```
<div class="" >
    <iframe class="somediv" ...>
```

then will works in chrome, ff and ie9, but still not in safari...

The code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .somediv {
      -moz-border-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
      -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      border: 2px solid red;
      height: 225px;
      width: 400px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="somediv" >
    <iframe class="" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/30239097?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could just do this to work around the problem.
Put the same class on both.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .somediv {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="somediv" >
    <iframe class="somediv" width="400" height="400" frameborder="0" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/30239097?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```